# Installing Hydro & Fuerte

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to install Hydro & Fuerte on ubuntu 12.04.

I'm wandering that they are interfering with themselves.

I am completely new to linux, so any help would be greatly appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194935/installing-hydro-&-fuerte/) by [KeigoM](https://answers.ros.org/users/20447/keigom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understood it correctly, you can only have 1 installation active at the same time, but both can be installed on the same system.

You can switch between the active installation via `source /opt/ros/<hydro or fuerte>/setup.bash`. You either enter this line in each new terminal you open, or you edit your `/home/<your_username>/.bashrc` to include corresponding source-command. In  this case, it is sourced automaticly each time you open a terminal.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2014-10-15**:
That's all correct. Just make sure you source only one setup.bash at a time.